# springboot for backend reactjs frontend

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

i use springboot and reactjs everthing was working before adding security to backend, now as go to web page to retrieve my data, i do not see any data there. I go to console it says the username not defined:do not know what does it mean.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/users/undefined/todos. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

UPDATE:  I tried to both code but did not help.
does this mean anything serious:

```
 "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError" (createError.js:16)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/users/undefined/todos' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:8080/users/undefined/todos net::ERR_FAILED
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13

todos:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/users/undefined/todos' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:8080/users/undefined/todos net::ERR_FAILED
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
```

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)

Comment: Are you sure your Spring app is running? If so, post the backend's stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` (if you run your client at 3000), or use this bean (in SecurityConfig):

```
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token", "xsrf-token"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```